# Getting list of fields from a table

Tags: rethinkdb

I understand this command will produce a list of fields ("keys") for a given "document"

```
r.table('users').get(1).keys()
```

My question: Is there a command that gives all possible unique key names for all of the documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [`keys`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/keys/).
2. [`map`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/map/) it.
3. [`reduce`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/reduce/) it.
4. [`distinct`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/distinct/) on result array.

Query:

```
r.table('users').map(function(doc){
  return doc.keys();
}).reduce(function(uniq, doc){
  return uniq.setUnion(doc);
}).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you. I also got this to work to give me the unique keys of a sub key: r.db("test").table("gleif").map(function(doc){
  return doc("lei:LEIRecord")("lei:Entity").keys();
}).reduce(function(uniq, doc){
  return uniq.setUnion(doc);
}).distinct()